# Event in a function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I know how to use events with jQuery in the classical way for example:

```
$("#moveArea").mousemove(function(event){
    $("#info").empty().append("pageX is: "+event.pageX);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ey7kP/

My question is how to pass the event in a function I have already create. I need something like the following, but I don't know how to achieve this

```
function cursorPos(event) {
  $("#info").empty().append("pageX is: "+event.pageX);      
}

$("#moveArea").mousemove(cursorPos(event));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do

```
$("#moveArea").mousemove(cursorPos);
```

Since you're referring to the function and not calling it, there's no need for passing the arguments. jQuery will call it for you and pass `event` to it.

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than this. Good job +1

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to pass any event variable. jQuery will pass it when it executes the handlers. Just say.

```
$("#moveArea").mousemove(cursorPos);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pass the argument as it is defaulted to `event`.  By placing the function name itself, `cursorPos` within your `mousemove()` event, you are capturing the necessary `event` thus rendering the need to pass the argument unnecessary.

```
function cursorPos(event){
     $("#info").empty().append("pageX is: "+event.pageX);
}

$("#moveArea").mousemove(cursorPos);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8v4uE/